# Delaying individual message in SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sqs-fifo

I want to exponentially delay processing SQS messages when the earlier message processing fails.  All the solution I have seen utilizes a lambda function and one or more DLQ.  We aren't allowed to use Lambda yet.  How can I achieve the same result without using a Lambda function.  Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "exponentially delay processing SQS messages"? Are you wanting to delay messages from being sent _into_ the Amazon SQS queue, or delay them from being initially visible in the queue, or delay fetching them from the queue? What is currently retrieving the messages -- is it an app you have written? Can't you just code a delay into that app? Please Edit your question to add these details.

Comment: Sorry - got sidetracked,  I want to deploy them from being initially visible in the queue.

Comment: You just want to **delay** them from being initially visible in the queue? When sending a message to an Amazon SQS queue, you can specify `DelaySeconds` up to 15 minutes. "Messages with a positive DelaySeconds value become available for processing after the delay period is finished." However, that could be a problem if you wish to send many messages, each separated by a time period, if they would then exceed a 15-second delay. Please Edit your question to add more details about what you are wanting to achieve.